# If a column has a certain string then perform some operation to get new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know similar questions have been asked earlier but i couldn't find a way to solve my problem.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
item   amount   currency   type          location
chair   69        $        type red       Miami
sofa   430       rupee     type yellow    Karnataka
```

and this is the output that I want:

```
item   charge1  charge2  charge3  currency location
chair   69        69       69       $       Miami
sofa    430      860      860     rupee     Karnataka
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
for i in df['type']:
    if 'red' in i:
        df['charge1'] = df['amount']
        df['charge2'] = df['amount']
        df['charge3'] = df['amount']
    if 'yellow' in i:
        df['charge1'] = df['amount']
        df['charge2'] = str((df['amount'].astype(int)) * 2)     
        df['charge3'] = str((df['amount'].astype(int)) * 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `for loop` in this case, instead use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign) + [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains) to create a boolean mask.

```
df = df.assign(
    charge1=df['amount'], charge2=df['amount'], charge3=df['amount']
)

df.loc[df['type'].str.contains('yellow'), ['charge2', 'charge3']] *= 2
```

---

```
    item  amount currency         type   location  charge1  charge2  charge3
0  chair      69        $     type red      Miami       69       69       69
1   sofa     430    rupee  type yellow  Karnataka      430      860      860
```